# Bookshelf.js is changing the password on every update to data using bcrypt

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bcrypt, bookshelf.js

My User Model is

```
var Bookshelf = require('../../db').bookshelf;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var Promise  = require('bluebird');
var Base = require('./../helpers/base');

// User model
var User_Model = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users',
    initialize: function() {
        this.on('saving', this.hashPassword, this);
    },
    hashPassword: function(model, attrs, options) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            bcrypt.hash(model.attributes.password, 10, function(err, hash) {
                if( err ) reject(err);
                model.set('password', hash);
                resolve(hash); // data is created only after this occurs
            });
        });
    }
});
```

On creating the user the password is set to

```
$2a$10$QD6FmChgGZEMooCklLfemOvAaHHV2RfUMQ5EoNwuMeojb6y2Hh2iK
```

And working perfectly on login,

When any update is made to the user field, it causes the password change everytime to random value

```
$2a$10$IVW.2JN/TPVABsx73t870uwKMNsDKoGmLJzOs1y/MPMOe.WRMBL4W

$2a$10$12sjEqM3t345dcq7rDixgu.9TZiWOC.JN5Ke8SI2F0IXv/YpdRwTK
```

Comment: On a side note - you should checkout async/await in nodejs 8.0. Rather than using Promise in the way you are using async/await is more concise syntax and makes code easy to read.

Some links :
[link here](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9)

[link Promisifying-core-libraries](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/promises-in-node-js-8-x-core-d6a8a93e85a2)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using bookshelfjs. You can make use of [Bookshelf-bycrypt plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bookshelf-bcrypt)
It takes care of hashing the password. When updating the table row mention update explicitly as follows

```
model.save([key], [val], [attrs], [options])


// update authors set "bio" = 'Short user bio' where "id" = 1
new Author({id: 1, first_name: 'User'})
  .save({bio: 'Short user bio'}, {method: "update" }{patch: true},)
  .then(function(model) {
     // ...
  });
```

Comment: does not {patch: true} imply update . I mean can't we skip the {method: "update" } part ?